# Extracting arguments into into class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for the best way to extract a class from an argument list that has gotten too long in one of my services. I have tried following a few articles and posts on here but no luck. My code:

**app/services/location/update_event.rb**

```
class Location::UpdateEvent
  def self.call(location:, event_id:, created_by:, city_details: nil, city_description: nil, city_weather: nil, city_location: nil )
    # Would like to to extract the above city arguments into its own class called city_info

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      LocationEvent.create(
        event: Event.find(event_id),
        location: location,
        # Here is where this data is then being sent to another servixe
        city_details: city_details,
        city_description: city_description,
        city_weather: city_weather,
        city_location: city_location,
        entered_at: Time.zone.now
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Here is what I tried, and replaced the 4 arguments with `city_info:` in update_location.rb.

**app/services/event/city_info.rb**

```
class CityInfo
  attr_accessor :city_details, :city_description, :city_weather, :city_location

  def initialize(
    city_details: nil,
    city_description: nil,
    city_weather: nil,
    city_location: nil)

    @city_details = city_details
    @city_description = city_description
    @city_weather = city_weather
    @city_location = city_location
  end
end
```

And finally, here is the update method from the controller that originally accepts the params, and sends them to the service. These need to be able to be nil on occasion.

```
def update
  authorize(location)
  @location = Location::UpdateEvent.call(
    location: location,
    event_id: params[:event_id],
    created_by: current_user,
    city_details: params[:city_details],
    city_description: params[:city_description],
    city_weather: params[:city_weather],
    city_location: params[:city_location]
  )

  @location.reload
  @location  = LocationDecorator.new(@location)
end
```

Comment: Why is `city_details` repeated 3 times in `create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only reason for the class is to hold a certain argument structure I'd use a [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Struct.html).

```
CityInfo = Struct.new(:details, :description, :weather, :location, keyword_init: true)

class Location::UpdateEvent
  def self.call(location:, event_id:, created_by:, city_info: CityInfo.new)
    city_info = city_info.to_h

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      LocationEvent.create(city_info.merge(
        event: Event.find(event_id),
        location: location,
        entered_at: Time.zone.now
      ))
    end
  end
end
```

controller:

```
def update
  authorize(location)
  city_info = CityInfo.new(city_info_params)

  @location = Location::UpdateEvent.call(
    location: location,
    event_id: params[:event_id],
    created_by: current_user,
    city_info: city_info
  )

  @location.reload
  @location  = LocationDecorator.new(@location)
end

private

def city_info_params
  params
    .permit(:city_details, :city_description, :city_weather, :city_location)
    .transform_keys { |key| key.delete_prefix('city_') }
end
```

You need Ruby 2.5 or higher to use the `:keyword_init` `Struct#new` option and `String#delete_prefix`.

---

Preferably you don't prefix the parameters with `city_` to start with, but I don't know if this is an option.

When you generate your form elements with the names:

```html
<input name="city[details]" type="..." value="..." />
```

```rb
def city_info_params
  params
    .fetch(:city, ActionController::Parameters.new)
    .permit(:details, :description, :weather, :location)
end
```

Would then be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash for an argument.

```
class CityInfo
  attr_accessor :city_details, :city_description, :city_weather, :city_location

  def initialize(args = {})
    args.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set(:"@#{k}", v);
    end 
  end
end
```

Remember that your code is only as readable as someone who hasn't read it thinks it is. I don't personally see you as having too many arguments; I know what to pass and that's what matters. This meta approach sacrifices legibility in favor of coolness, which isn't necessarily correct. Given this code won't change frequently, or be used elsewhere in your application, I think your code as it stands is acceptable.